# MongoError exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-migration

We just migrated our infrastructure on AWS from one account to another. 
The mongo version installed on the server is 2.4.9
I am new to MongoDb and faced the following 2 errors when I ran the web app -

```
{"name":"MongoError","errmsg":"exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.","code":16410,"ok":0}
```

and

```
{"name":"MongoError","errmsg":"exception: the $cond operator requires an array of 3 operands","code":16019,"ok":0}
```

The web app was working on our previous instances. Can anyone point me in  the right direction?

Comment: It will be better if you provide query here. There is change in package name in mongo 2.6 and 2.4. This link might be useful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011193/using-root-in-aggregation-order

Comment: Can you provide your MongoDB driver version and an example of the query? Also, what were the previous MongoDB driver & server versions you migrated from?

Comment: Part of example query where we're facing this error : 
`{ 
             $group: {
                 _id: "$brand_id", twitter: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
             }
         }`

The problem is, our previous server instances have been terminated and we cannot check the version we were using on them. However, I am almost certain that it was 2.6.
How do I check my MongoDb driver version?
Also, will I need to take a backup if I update my mongodb version from 2.4 to 2.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest mongodb (3.0.2) helped resolve this issue for me.

P.S. - Make sure you kill the mongod process already running using killall -15 instead of pkill -9 as the latter could cause damage.